# Use Windows as a router

Tags: windows, networking, routing, nat, netsh

I need a client application to connect to a server in a different network. Another computer is connected to both networks as shown here:

```
   Client                         Computer                        Server
192.168.1.10 <---------> 192.168.1.20  192.168.2.30 <---------> 192.168.2.40
              network 1                              network 2
               (wifi)                                (ethernet)
```

I need the middle computer (Windows) to act as a router to forward any connection to port 502 to the server. Network 2 is an internal network of an industrial machine, so I'd like to keep it separate from the main network 1 as much as possible, and avoid reconfiguring routers. That means only connecting to the middle computer and redirecting the packets from there if possible.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I already tried `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=502 listenaddress=192.168.1.20 connectport=502 connectaddress=192.168.2.40` which works well, but only until the next reboot. If the rule is created or activated just before the wifi connects, it doesn't work, even though it is still visible in `netsh interface portproxy show all`. Only deleting and recreating the rule, or restarting the `iphlpsvc` service can get it to work again. Is there a way to fix this?

Is there a better tool, or a better way to do it, like using simple routing or a similar technique? Or are NAT and port forwarding required?

Comment: Simply enable routing on the Windows computer, which is the easy part, then you need to configure a static route on the client to use `192.168.1.20` as the gateway to reach network 2, and configure a static route on the server to use `192.168.2.30` as the gateway to reach network 1.

Comment: If you want to keep the networks separated as much as possible I suggest you go for a proxy solution instead of routing. Port 502 is typically used for Modbus. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried `listenaddress=0.0.0.0` to deal with the interfacing connecting and disconnecting?

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt yes, it is a Modbus server on a PLC. Know of any good tool for that?

Comment: @RonMaupin That is a good solution thank you. Not sure if the server can be configured that way though, it is not a standard computer

Comment: None for Windows I'm afraid. There's a Python one at https://pypi.org/project/modbus-proxy/ but I don't know whether it can be made to work on Windows.

Comment: There is a registry entry called IPEnableRouter.

Comment: `better way to do it` typically network design and data flows are logged, including the configuration. Using netsh isn't particularly undesirable, but more obtuse from a documentation perspective and systematic data collection of the environment. Probably simpler to slap a scheduled task on it to test the connection every five minutes and reset it if the connection is not working, trigger would be at system start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the simplest solution is to use `listenaddress=0.0.0.0` which does seem to make `netsh portproxy` more reliable.

A better way to do it would be to use or develop a proxy application.